# Does usage of contains on IEnumerable cast it to a List?

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I'm using Linq to filter Data I get from the database. Due to design choices made 1 method returns me an `IEnumerable<int>` which I then use for a linq statement to see which IDs are permitted to be returned (code follows below). My question here is as I'm not seeing anything there in the documentation: Does the Contains method implicitly cast the IEnumerable to a List for the statement to be executed? (If so the question is if using List in the first place instead of IEnumerable is better).

**Code Example**

```
private List<MyData> GetAllPermittedData()
{
    IEnumerable<int> permitteddIds = GetPermittedIDs();
    return (from a in MyDataHandler.GetAllData() where permittedIds.Contains(a.Id)
            select a);
}
```

Like I asked above I'm not sure if the `Contains` part implicitly converts permittedIds into a `List<int>` (for/inside the use of the Contains statement). If this is the case then a followup question would be if it is not better to already use the following statement instead (performance-wise):

```
private List<MyData> GetAllPermittedData()
{
    List<int> permitteddIds = GetPermittedIDs().ToList();
    return (from a in MyDataHandler.GetAllData() where permittedIds.Contains(a.Id)
            select a);
}
```

Comment: Linq Extension on IEnumerable just enumerate the IEnumerable whenever possible. (With .Contains() it is possible)

Comment: @DrKoch ok so there is no implizit conversion to List?

Comment: No, Linq does lazy evaluation by default, which is why tools like ReSharper will flag sequential calls as "multiple enumeration of ienumerable". If, however, the enumerable is already a List, it makes no difference.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f60bab4c5e27a849

Comment: @mason the mainproblem is that the data there is so low in numbers that it is not measureable anyway if it is a performance boost or not. Also I only thought about the ToList conversion while writing down the question (the mainthing for me was the question if there is an implizit conversion or not as I wasn't sure there)

Comment: I'd like to add an IEnumerable<T> can not be "cast" to a List<T>, considering the list would be the wider type. Not really relevant, though.

Comment: @EmilePels good point though. Although I have to admit I'm not sure how I could best describe what I wanted to describe without that technical error in my description^^'

Comment: If you really want to improve the code, then pass those `permitteddIds` to a method in `MyDataHandler` that can use them in the query sent to the db, which is where this kind of filtering really belongs, IMHO.

Comment: @Thomas Looking at the source code for IEnumerable<T>.ToList(), it simply creates a new object of List<T> and passes itself as an argument. There, it's either handled as an ICollection<T> and CopyTo() is called, or it enumerates the IEnumerable<T> and adds every item to the list one-by-one.

Answer (score 3):

The LINQ operator will attempt to cast it to `ICollection<T>` first. If the cast succeeds, it uses that method. Since `List<T>` implements this interface, it will use the list's contain method.

Note that if you use the overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer`, it must iterate over the enumerable and the `ICollection` shortcut is not taken.

You can see this implementation in the .NET Framework [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1242):

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value) {
        ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
        if (collection != null) return collection.Contains(value);
        return Contains<TSource>(source, value, null);
}
```

Jon Skeet also has a good (and lengthy) blog series called "Reimplementing LINQ" where he discusses the implementation in depth. He specifically covers `Contains` in [part 32 of his blog](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/12/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-32-contains/).

Answer (score 0):

The [`Contains` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) *may* try to cast the passed [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or to [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If the cast succeeds, it may directly use the methods of `IList<T>`, otherwise it will enumerate over the full sequence.

Note that I am writing *may* because this is implementation-specific and it is not specified in the docs. As such, it could be different across .NET versions and also in alternative implementations such as Mono.

Your advantage by providing only an `IEnumerable<T>` is that you have more freedom to exchange the object returned from that property without changing the public interface. The performance cost of the attempted cast to `IList<T>` or similar should be negligible.

In any case, this way is more performant than your suggestion of calling [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), as that will actually create a new [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and copy all items from the enumeration into it.

Answer (score -1):

`Contains` exists as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) for `IEnumerable<T>`. But you con't need to convert your IEnumerable to a `List<T>` with `ToList()`, you could simply use that `IEnumerable<T>` to [fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354549(v=vs.110).aspx) a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var permitteddIds = new HashSet<int>(GetPermittedIDs());
```